# Where is the real ClickOnce published app's configuration file?

Tags: c#, clickonce

I'm using this to get the location of my application's config file:

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
```

But it doesn't give me the path to the file that is actually being used.

My problem is that, I need my application to be runnable from the Windows Task Scheduler, and I want it to take parameters. The way I've been doing it is, when I create a task in the Scheduler, click Browse and locate the `appref-ms` icon. Then the Scheduler will fill the text box where I'd enter the path to the file with the path to a weird location under `AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\...` (instead of just keeping the path to the icon). This way I can also add arguments and everything works fine unlike other things I've tried such as using the path to the `.exe` file or typing the path to the icon, except that...

When the application is launched from the Task Scheduler it uses a different config file than when is launched with the icon. Say I change setting `S` to value `T` (always from within the application) after running it from the Task Scheduler. Then I change setting `S` to `I` when I run it from the icon. The next time I run the application from the Task Scheduler, setting `S` will be `T` and the next time I run it from the icon, setting `S` will be `I`. Also, setting `S` inside the file at the path the code above gives me, is just the default value (which is not `T` nor `I`).

This is a big problem because I need my settings to be the same no matter how I'm running the application. I'm considering replacing the default settings file for my own file with a location determined by myself. Is this my only choice? Is there any other way to run the application from the Task Scheduler such that I'll be able to pass arguments that will also use the same config file as when I run it from the icon? How about a piece of code that would force the application to use always the same config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the settings to a place that everyone can find them. If it's anything that's saved, you'll want to do this anyway, as ClickOnce updates can wipe out the user's saved settings.

Comment: This also implies I won't be able to use `Properties.Settings.Default...` is this right?

Comment: I don't use the Settings files that are built-in for .NET projects. If you do let ClickOnce handle them, sometimes it copies them forward and sometimes it doesn't. It will deploy anything new, so if you have defaults you want to use, that will work, but if you change them it won't. I wrote my own configuration manager that writes out key/value pairs to an XML config file that I store outside of the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can get the application installed path from

```
INSTALLED_PATH = Application.StartupPath ;
```

One approach could be that the first launch of the application, after each ClicOnce deployment, would be from the the icon. If the application then saves INSTALLED_PATH to a fixed text file, then the task could get the path from there. Does that makes sense ?